# Expectation of sequence does not converge to expectation of the limit of sequence

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of non-negative random variables with $X_n \rightarrow X$ for some random variable $X$.

Assume $E[X_n]$ does not converge to $E[X]$ then I want to show that there exist a positive $\epsilon$ such that $E[X_n] \geq E[X] + \epsilon$ for infinitely many n.

Here's what I have tried.

1. Apply Fatou lemma to show that ${\lim \inf}_{n \rightarrow \infty} E[X_n] \geq E[\lim \inf_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n] = E[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n] = E[X]$ since $X_n$ converges to $X$. I'm not quite sure how to continue from here, but I'm guessing to use some definition of $\lim \inf$?

Any hints is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $E[X_n]$ doesn't converge to $E[X_n]$, your work (1.) implies that either $\liminf_n E[X_n]> E[X]$ or that $\liminf_n E[X_n]= E[X]$ and $\limsup_n E[X_n]>\liminf_nE[X_n]$. Each possibility will give you your result after unpacking the definitions of liminf and limsup.

Comment: Can you provide some hints on which definition of lim inf & Iim sup to use? A little bit more guidance will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: @finmathstudent: How about the one that says there's a subsequence $X_{n_k}$ such that $E[X_{n_k}]$ converges to the liminf or limsup.

Comment: yes, i figured it out. Thanks. What I used was, there exist $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq K$, $E[X_n] > \lim \inf E[Xn] - \epsilon$. Now choose $\epsilon = 0.5( \lim \inf E[X_n] - E[X])$ then we are good to go!